# Encoding problem with node odbc and advantage database server

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, odbc, advantage-database-server

I have recently updated to the current node odbc version (2.1.3). Since then I have problem with correct encoding of german special characters (üäöß). The older version of node odbc (<2.0) was working fine.

This is my code:

```
    const cn = `DRIVER=Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC; UID=${settings.db.username}; PWD=${settings.db.password}; Language=ANSI; EncryptionType=RC4; Rows=False, TrimTrailingSpaces=True;DataDirectory=dd.add`;
    let sql = 'Select top 2 name from touren'
    let connection = await db.connect(cn);
    let data = await connection.query(sql)
    
    console.log(data)
```

And this is the output:

```
[
  { name: 'Rietberg              ' },
  { name: 'G�tersloh             ' },
  statement: 'Select top 2 name from touren',
  parameters: undefined,
  return: undefined,
  count: -1,
  columns: [ { name: 'name', dataType: 1 } ]
]
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please [review your question to improve it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I've added the used code and the produced output.